# Spring Batch Partition not work as expected

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch partition job. Basically what is does is it will process rows of data in db and give some output. But the log I got it doesn't partition it correctly. Record  table has processed and result flag, when finish processing, it will set result flag to Y, processed Flag will still be N. Because itemreader is doing select on processed flag, so I don't want to change it during processing. That is why I add result flag. There will  be another job to set processed to result when this partition  job is done.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public dbItemReader(@Value("${executionContext[from]}") Long from, @Value("${executionContext[to]}") Long to,
    @Value("${executionContext[partitionId]}") Long partitionId){
        RepositoryItemReader<Record>  itemReader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setRepository(dataRepo);
        //Select record from Record record where processed=:processed and rownum >=:from and rownum < :to;
        itemReader.setMethod("findByProcessedBetweenFromAndTo");
        List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.put("N");
        params.put(from);
        params.put(to);
        itemReader.setArguments(params);
        return itemReader;
}

@Bean
public dbItemProcessor(){
        RecordItemProcessor<Record>  itemProcessor = new RecordItemProcessor<>();
        return itemProcessor;
}

@Bean
public writer(){
    RepositoryItemWriter writer = new RepositoryItemWriter();
    writer.setRepository(dataRepo);
    writer.setMethod("save");
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Partition partitioner() {
    Partition p = new Partition();
    p.setTotalCount(dataRepo.count());
    return p;
}

//Partition class just @override method
@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>(gridSize);
    int start = 1;
    int range = this.totalCount / gridSize + 1;
    for (int i=0; to gridSize) {
        ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
        context.putString("from", start);
        context.putString("to", start + range);
        context.putString("partitionId", i);
        start += range;
        map.put("Partition"+ i, context);
    }
    return map;
} 

@Bean
public Step slaveStep() 
  throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {
    return steps.get("slaveStep").<Record, Record>chunk(1)
      .reader(dbItemReader(null,null,null))
      .processor(dbItemProcessor())
      .writer(itemWriter())
      .build();
}

@Bean
public Step partitionStep() 
  throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {
    return steps.get("partitionStep")
      .partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner())
      .step(slaveStep())
      .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
      .gridSize(10)
      .build();
}

//omit job setup
```

Above are sample code, the whole idea is that I will partition the whole db as 10 partitions, say totalCount is 100, each partition will reader 1-10, 10-20 so on. So in the end all 100  will be processed and set Result to Y. But when this partition job finishes, there are still records has  result=N, that means some record was skipped.

When I check the log, the itemprocessor is somehow processing duplicate records

```
Thread 10 - Info: Processing record: 2
Thread 4 - Info: Processing record: 40
Thread 3 - Info: Processing record: 20
so  on
//after some time, there will be threads reading the same record again
Thread 5 - Info: Processing record: 20 //it suppose process 60-70 for example
```

I was thinking if I partition the data into 10 partitions, each should have their own set of data to process and should never touch another set of data.
Right? It is what the partition is for? Button line is all data should be processed. There are multiple partition jobs and they might run simultaneously.

I don't know what I did wrong, so I need some help.

Comment: Are you sure your partitions are distinct? Can you share the result of your partitioner for 100 items (aka the from/to values for each partition) as well as your partition handler configuration? That said, it could be possible that a worker processes more than one partition if you have more partitions than workers, but in all cases, records should not be processed twice if correctly partitioned.

Comment: I added a log in itemreader, it logs like "Partition: 1 processes from 20 to 30, partition 2 processes 1-10", log has the right output, meanning each partition got right from and to and there is no overlap. I have 10 threads running because of gridSize 10, the worker and partition count should match. Not sure what do you mean by distinct? And I don't have partition handler in my configuration, is it required?

Comment: by "distinct" I mean there is no overlap between partitions. The partition handler is not required, the default one is `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler`. I just asked to make sure you don't have a custom one. Now with that said, I can't see from what you shared why some records are processed twice, that should not be the case. Your understanding is correct. Please share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on github or somewhere else to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I  can't really share the code. However, I have a thought, since I made ItemReader  stepscope, is it possible that everytime when ItemReader do read, it will create a new object so when it does a do read, it will restarted from begining?

Comment: The scope of the reader is not related to your issue. Regardless of the reader's scope, items should not be processed twice.

Comment: I feel like the hql I am using is wrong, I have oracle db. So the getting the  data between from from and  to is different. I will try the new hql and keep you posted.

Comment: Somehow it is impossible to do a manual partition of data and then for that specific chunk do pagination. I've tried with multiple queries but still no luck. Check  out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56205261/how-to-have-order-by-inside-a-query-with-pageable-parameter, I wrote  down the problem I am facing.